# Install geth 1.4.6 on Mac

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx

I'm looking to install geth 1.4.6 that syncs much faster than 1.4.5. Unfortunately doing `brew upgrade ethereum` only updates geth to version 1.4.5.

How can I get geth 1.4.6 for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geth 1.4.7 (the release fixing homebrew) should be available now :)

Answer (score 3):

**geth** is a Go program with one unique file and does not have any dependency. You could download the file here:

https://bintray.com/karalabe/ethereum/geth/1.4.6-stable-0f036f6/view

Simply replace the one in the /usr/local/bin or use it where it is.

Comment: Which of the executables should be used on Mac OS X?

Comment: The darwin amd64 version. Btw, we're going to push out a tiny windows console color fix release in a few days, which also fixes the homebrew issue (build server failure) that prevented the osx distribution.

Comment: like Peter said, the darwin amd64. On Unix, use  'uname -a' to know your os